# the logout button is not in the usual spot. how to logout?

Tags: support

The answer to previous "logout question" is not accurate anymore, so where did they hide the logout button?
I went to the usual place I used to logout last time in the left drop-down list but now there is no logout button there [+nor even any drop-down list. edited by request]

Comment: Are you...sure there's none in the dropdown list anymore? I can very clearly see it right there. Remember that the dropdown list has been moved to the right. There is no logout button in the dropdown list on the left, but...there's no dropdown list on the left anymore to begin with. If, however, you're asking where the entire dropdown list went, which certainly is a reasonable question, you might want to clarify that a bit.

Comment: @TARS The question doesn't say it's not in the dropdown list any more, only that it's not in the *left* drop-down.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yeah, that's why I find the question quite confusing and unclear. There *is* no left dropdown. So I don't know if he really means the dropdown or if he is looking for the dropdown itself.

Comment: Related: [New top bar is live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/new-top-bar-is-live)

Comment: tars your answer was the data i needed much thanks :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is now in the right hand drop down list. Click the furthest right button on the top bar and there should be the same drop down list you used last time with a log out button in the top right corner.

[image]

Comment: yes. too bad they do not make a designated logout button clearly visible like quality websites.

Comment: @tal: What quality websites would those be?  Even Google buries the logout button inside of the top right picture-of-you-that-doesn't-have-a-label popout.  I'm pretty sure hiding logout inside of a top right popout is pretty standard at this point.